# Compiling PHP with LDAP support on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, php, ldap

I am trying to compile PHP on Ubuntu 12.10 with LDAP support. I have run:

```
apt-get install libldap2-dev
```

That installs the header files to `/usr/include`.

However, when attempting to compile it is unable to locate the header files. I have tried to with `--with-ldap=/usr/include` as well and it still fails with:

```
configure: error: Cannot find ldap.h
```

I also tried symlinking with the following and I still get the same error:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/ldap* /usr/lib/
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something here, but why are you **compiling** LDAP support in Ubuntu?  There is a package in the repos for it: `sudo apt-get install php5-ldap`

Comment: `php5-ldap` installs `php5-common`, which for some reason installs PHP 5.4.6~ubuntu CLI. I'm compiling PHP 5.4.8 from source.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49876 explains this behavior.

To fix this, simply run the following:

```
ln -fs /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so /usr/lib/
```

Vola, compiling away.

Comment: Also worth noting in case you're wondering... `--with-libdir=lib64` causes other parts of the configuration to fail. This is why you have to symlink lib64 libraries individually.

Comment: confirmed fix for Ubuntu 13.10